# What is a mechanism with teeth like this called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad

I'm trying to describe a part that I'm designing that has a disc with incremental teeth, like what is pictured here; which mates with a similar part. What is this type mechanism called? And what are the "teeth" called (for some reason I thought they were called detents, but found that not to be the case)?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would call that a swivel mount with detents. if the teeth are sharp they are sometimes called ratchet detents.

Comment: That sounds about right. When I googled "detents", the examples seemed limited to a latching mechanism (like in a clock), which is what confused me.

Comment: In my experience/opinion, the teeth here really are just teeth. A detent implies some sort of spring force that ‘clicks into place’, where this is held by a manually tightened bolt. Also, detent positions are usually functional (e.g. a dual snapping to round numbers). The teeth are simply there to drastically improve friction compared to two flat surfaces - the fact that you have fewer choices of angle is typically a side-effect rather than a feature...